# How to convert a SRID/SRS in PostGIS into Well Known Text (WKT)?

Tags: postgis, srid

Is there a PostGIS function for obtaining the WKT of an SRID in PostGIS?

By WKT, I mean the ones that can be [uploaded to spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/upload/).

I'm trying to create a new SRID/SRS by tweaking existing SRID/SRS. But couldn't find a way to obtain the WKT. Search results mostly show [ST_AsText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html), which is for converting geometry/geography to WKT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this request to get the PostGIS WKT srid where `srtext` is the WKT you are looking for (you can compare it with http://spatialreference.org although nowadays I only use http://epsg.io, a more up to date version)

```sql
SELECT srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext AS wkt, proj4text
FROM public.spatial_ref_sys
WHERE srid = 2154;
```

PS: `spatial_ref_sys` structure/content is documented at https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#spatial_ref_sys